# Instantiate multiple objects of a class most efficiently

Tags: python, class, object

I am writing some python code and I have a roman numeral class that I created. It works much the same as the built in roman() class.
I want to instantiate roman numbers from 1 to 1000 without having to actually instantiate each one myself. 
For Example:

```
I = roman(1)
II = roman(2)
.... up to M = roman(1000)
```

Assuming I already have a way to convert numbers to roman numerals, what would be the most efficient way of doing this?

So someone should be able to import * from the roman module and type in something like:

```
IV * I + II * V
```

and get...

roman(14)

So in other words.. each roman numeral is its own object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### As a Dictionary

Since you're essentially mapping strings like `"IV"` to objects of your `roman` class, you should probably keep them in a dictionary instead of the local namespace.  Assuming your `roman`'s `__str__(self)` method returns strings like `"I"` and `"XV"`, you can declare the dictionary like this:

```py
ROMANS = {
  str(r): r for r in (
    roman(i) for i in range(1, 1000 + 1)
    )
  }
```

Now you can access individual `roman` objects as `ROMANS["XXIV"]` and so on.

(That dictionary comprehension and generator expression combo is ugly enough that I would probably hide it in a function called `_romans_dict(upper=1000)`.)

### As a Bunch of Variables

If you *really* want to access the `roman(7)` object by way of a variable named `VII`, you can update your local namespace with the dictionary you just created.  You can even throw away the dictionary's name after the update.  (Fortunately, all-caps Roman numerals like "VII" match Python's naming conventions for module-level constants.)

```py
# ROMANS = ...same as above
locals().update(ROMANS)
del(ROMANS)  # optional
```

The wisdom of spamming your module's namespace with a thousand or more Roman numerals is a different question.  (For starters, my syntax checker screams at me for using variables like `VII` and `XIX` that it can't find declared anywhere.  Your boss might scream at you, too.)

### A Final Quibble

Your `roman` class should probably be spelled `Roman`.  Python class names are (usually) in StudlyCaps.

Comment: If I wanted to import from this module and perform roman numeral calculations like IV * I + II * V.. wouldn't I want to say

    globals().update(ROMANS)
instead of locals()?

Comment: @JayronHubbard: At the module-level scope (where imports are typically done), `globals() is locals()` is `True`, so there's no difference.  And anyone who updates a subordinate namespace, like inside a function definition, presumably doesn't _want_ these wacky romans leaking out into the surrounding namespaces.

Comment: @JayronHubbard:  Also, while I cringe a bit at the thought of `import * from ANYTHING`, I could see this sort of thing being a rare case where it's actually worth the risk.  Not so much for Roman numerals, but a chemist might love being able to `import * from elements_constants` and then write simple code like `octane = C+H*3 + (C+H*2)*6 + C+H*3` or `salt_mass = Na.mass + Cl.mass`.  I would consider creating a module containing these constants and _nothing else_, so the `import *` wouldn't suck in all the helper functions, classes, and other variables along with the useful constants.

Answer (score 0):

```
numerals = [roman(i) for i in range(1, 1001)]
print(numerals)
```

That'll give you a list of roman numerals from 1 to 1000. You can then access individual numbers if you wish. Note that the indices will be off by 1 since list indices start at 0 but roman numerals start at 1.

```
print(numerals[0])    # I
print(numerals[9])    # X
print(numerals[999])  # M
```